# Endless Scrolling List View in android

Tags: android

I am displaying list of records using List View. I am loading records when user scroll to end.

Here my problem is records is loading but scroll goes to first record every time and how to end when records all are loaded.

Comment: Please add your code and the list the exact error wat you get. And don't add thank you to your questions.

Answer (score 3):

You mean when the user reaches the bottom of the `ListView` you load additional data, but then the `ListView` jumps back up to the top of the `ListView`?

That is probably because you reset the adapter. Try modifying the data source of the adapter and then calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter like this:

In your Adapter you have some kind of datasource like a list of all items, create a public getter for these items:

```
public List<ListViewItem> getItems() {
   return this.items;
}
```

Then when you load additional items you get the list from the adapter and add your items:

```
List<ListViewItem> items = adapter.getItems();
items.addAll(newItems);
```

And after that you call notifyDataSetChanged() to tell the adapter that you changed the datasource:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```